# Getting the current age using datetime library

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a column of a user's DOB data in datetime64[ns] format, and would like to calculate their current age. Every time I parse this date and try to subtract the same with the present date, it throws me an error of str and datetime data format invalidity.

```
from datetime import datetime
main_file['AD_DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(main_file['AD_DOB']).dt.date ##10/2/1943
now = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
main_file['Age'] = ((now - main_file['AD_DOB'])/365).dt.days
```

Error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.date'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
from datetime import datetime
main_file['AD_DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(main_file['AD_DOB']).dt.date ##10/2/1943
now = datetime.datetime.now()
main_file['Age'] = ((now - main_file['AD_DOB'])/365).dt.days
```

Comment: It's running on the latest release, 0.25.3.

Answer (score 1):

It's because that `datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")` returns a string object

Below should work:

```
now = datetime.now()
main_file['Age'] = (now - main_file['AD_DOB']).days/365.0
```

Comment: Still threw an error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.date'. 

However, it worked well with the other solution. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

For subtract in pandas is necessary convert values to datetimes, if want remove times use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) for `AD_DOB` column and also for `now` is used [`Timestamp.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html):

```
main_file = pd.DataFrame({'AD_DOB':['10/2/1943','10/8/1946','10/12/1983']})
main_file['AD_DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(main_file['AD_DOB']).dt.floor('d')
now = pd.to_datetime('now').floor('d')
main_file['Age'] = ((now - main_file['AD_DOB'])/365).dt.days
print (main_file)
      AD_DOB  Age
0 1943-10-02   76
1 1946-10-08   73
2 1983-10-12   36
```